# Empty yellow banner in the review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design

There is an empty yellow banner showing up in the review queues.

[image]

That doesn't look like it's supposed to be there. Or is it just missing its content?

Comment: I poked a dev about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, that wasn't supposed to be there except in [this situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298526/155160). My bad. The fix is rolling out now.